# How can I install Ubuntu 13.04 on a Mac (using disk)?

Tags: installation, mac

I called a local computer store and they said Ubuntu 13.04 "doesn't like Mac" and it's very hard to do and requires lots of "codes". They said they would charge me $99 to do it. But I have read some articles online where people have done it themselves.

I am confused about what the computer guy said vs. people online. Please let me know how I can install it.

Comment: Also, I have a fall 2012 13" Macbook Pro, and would like to do a dual-boot type installation. I already have Windows 8 alongside OS X. Ubuntu will be the third.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a reasonable walkthrough for Mac OS X on burning the image, here, on the main ubuntu.com download pages:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx

From there, you should simply boot off of the burned disc (or, of course, a USB stick), but you'll likely need to have some already unused space available for Ubuntu to fit into.  If you've already allocated/fully partitioned all of your HDD space to the other two OSs, it will be a bit more work to restructure the partitions so you have some unallocated space available first.

Comment: I found that there are two different Ubuntu 13.04. One seems like it is both Windows/Mac compatible .iso file, and the other one I found was a "Ubuntu Desktop AMD64 Mac.iso". Which one should I use? Also, will I need a program like ReFIND to do the installation?